# Referring to named global expressions inside an event filter using EPStatementObjectModel (Esper)

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

I am aware that you can create global expressions with Esper's Statement Object Model using `CreateExpressionClause` and `ExpressionDeclaration`, but I'm not exactly sure how you are able to refer to their aliases when building an `EPStatementObjectModel` for a pattern.  For example, say I have a pattern like this:

```
every (a=Event(fizz = 3 and buzz = 5) -> b=Event(fizz = 3 and buzz = 5 and foo = 1 and bar = 2))
```

I would like to declare `fizz = 3 and buzz = 5` as a global expression as such:

```
create expression fizzbuzz alias for {fizz = 3 and buzz = 5}
```

Therefore, with EPL I could successfully simplify the pattern to the following:

```
every (a=Event(fizzbuzz) -> b=Event(fizzbuzz and foo = 1 and bar = 2))
```

I cannot seem to find a method in any of the classes in `com.espertech.esper.client.soda` in which I can refer to the global expression alias as I build the statement object.  The best thing I could think of that would give me a valid pattern when converting the statement object to EPL would involve `Expressions.property(alias)`, but I get the following error when I add the complete statement object to the Esper engine:

```
Failed to validate filter expression 'fizzbuzz': Property named 'fizzbuzz' is not valid in any stream [every (a=Event(fizzbuzz) -> b=Event(fizzbuzz and foo = 1 and bar = 2))]
```

Take note that a) global expressions were already declared at this point, b) If I add the pattern containing the global expression aliases in EPL form to the Esper engine, it works.

Any ideas?  While it's an option, I'd prefer not to convert from `EPStatementObjectModel` to an EPL string everytime I add a new pattern to the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inspect a generated object model in a debugger to find out. So in order to generate one, you could call "epadmin.compile("some epl with the expression") and see what comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Following user650839's advice, I found through debugging that the way to go about including the alias to named global expressions is to incorporate a `DotExpression` into your statement object tree as such:

```
DotExpression globalExpression = new DotExpression();
globalExpression.add("fizzbuzz", new ArrayList<Expression>(), true);
```